# How to code HTML download button where filename version will change

Tags: html, download

I'm creating a webpage where the user will be able to download an .iso file. The version of the iso will change. For example: xxxx.1.iso will become xxxx.2.iso when the iso is updated. How do I code the download button so that I don't need to re-code the button when the version changes. The .iso file will always be located in the root of the domain.

Thanks in advance

EDIT 1 - If I were to create a download subdirectory, and the .iso file was kept there instead of the root of the domain and it was the only file in that subdirectory, how would I get the filename for the download button?

EDIT 2 - Do you think this would work if the only file in the download subdirectory is the .iso file?

```
       <?php
        $files = array_slice(scandir('/download/'), 2); 
        ?>         
        <div class="navbar-custom">
           <a class="btn-solid-lg page-scroll" href="/Download/" download=$files>Download the App</a>
        </div>
```

Comment: do you manually update the version of .iso file in your root ?

Comment: @Godwin - Yes, we manually replace the old .iso with a new .iso that has a different version number.

Comment: can we access the filenames of your .iso path with code , that must be the solution

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that I understand well, but I understand that the filename of the `.iso` file that is stored on your server will change depending on the version of the file.
In this case you can store the filename of the last version in a file or a database and dynamically put this name in the `href` field of the download button (using Php for example, but also javascript or many other options).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if all your files will be xxxx.Y.iso so that you change only the number of the version. In that case you could use [strpos](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) to get get the version number and then you could just add it to a variable which you will later put in the download link of the button which could look like: `<input type="button" onClick="window.location='http://website.com/download/xxxx.<?php echo $version?>.iso'">`